# providing instructions to a series of map calls, generic issues

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream

of the code I want to write, basically looks like this `Persistable` is an interface in Spring Data with `getId` and `isNew`

```
    Optional<Pair<Persistable<Long>, <Persistable<Long>>> pair = Optional.of( Pair.of( prev, next ) );
    return Long.instructions()
        .map( instruction -> {
            return pair.map( extractPair( instruction.extractProperty() ) )
                .map( instruction.pairToBuilder() )
                .filter( Optional::isPresent )
        } );
```

Sometimes I want to convert the "Long" to a String, other times to an Integer. this is more hypothetical to reduce from complex objects.

I want to store my instructions in an Enum, the instruction interface currently looks like this.

```
interface Instruction<IN, OUT, BUILDER> {

<INPUT> Function<Pair<INPUT, INPUT>, Optional<BUILDER>> pairToBuilder()

Function<IN, OUT> extractProperty();

}
```

so currently these bits compile the problem comes when dealing with an actual implementation of instruction

```
public class PeristableInstruction<OUT> implements Instruction<Persistable<Long>, OUT, String>

private final Function<Persitable<Long>, OUT> extractProperty;
private Function<Pair<OUT, OUT>, Optional<String>> pairOptionalFunction;


@Override
public <INPUT> Function<Pair<INPUT, INPUT>, Optional<String>> pairToBuilder() {
    return this.pairOptionalFunction;
}

@Override
public Function<Persistable<Long>, OUT> extractProperty()
{
    return extractProperty;
}
```

here is the implementation of `extractPair` `Pair` is just `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair`

```
static <OUT, IN> Function<Pair<IN, IN>, Pair<OUT, OUT>> extractPair( final Function<IN, OUT> extract ) {
    return pair -> Pair.of( extract.apply( pair.getLeft() ), extract.apply( pair.getRight() ) );
}
```

the problem of course is that `INPUT` is not `OUT` but it should be, but if I change the signature to not use `INPUT` `.map` doesn't like it, and I can't think of a way to do this based not on that.

**update** although irrelevant, because the problem seems to be how specify an instruction field so that it's generically correct, here's the instructions source, this contains some *ished* code

```
SPECIFIC_INSTRUCTION( new PersistableInstructio<>( Persistable::Long, Long::toString, Builder::new ) );


private final Optional<PersistableInstruction<?>> instruction;

PersistableInstructions( final PersitableInstruction<?> instruction )
{
    this.instruction = Optional.ofNullable( instruction );
}

public static Stream<PersistableInstruction<?>> instructions() {
    return Stream.of( PersistableInstructions.values() )
        .map( PersistableInstructions::getInstruction )
        .filter( Optional::isPresent )
        .map( Optional::get );
}

public Optional<PersistableInstruction<?>> getInstruction()
{
    return instruction;
}
```

The generic intent is to provide an enum of instructions that can be provided to an Optional or Stream `map` method.

**I have successfully *inlined* method references and functions into map blocks, trying to loop over those functions instead of copying and pasting the map chain structure 100 times. How can I fix my generics structure to provide instructions to mapping implementation?**

a correct answer will provide compilable code, that does not use casting (since casting is my workaround).

Comment: I see both `IN` and `INPUT` in `Instruction` - is that intentional?

Comment: @Kenney yes because you basically have multiple sort of inputs the output of the first thing is the input to the 2nd, but the first thing also has a variant input. the use of Long and String here is meant to simplify the example, the transformations are actually on complex entities.

ideally INPUT, is the same as OUT, but I haven't found a way to accomplish that.

Comment: Could you add code for `Pair` and `extractPair`?

Comment: Pair, is the apache commons lang impl, but I can see about extractPair

Comment: Well, I can't get it to work without warnings (and possible runtime errors). I think you may need to remove the intermediary step converting from `Pair<IN,IN>` to `Pair<OUT,OUT>` and directly convert from `Pair<IN,IN>` to `Optional<BUILDER>`, because in the first `map()` conversion, the `OUT` is an anonymous "capture#1", and in the second conversion from `Pair<OUT,OUT>` to `Optional<BUILDER>`, that information is lost (a "capture#2").

Comment: How are we supposed to answer that without knowing what `Long.instructions()` is (what type it returns) or what target type the `return` instruction actually has? When I set reasonable types for them, everything works fine, so maybe the error lies in these declarations that are missing in your question.

Comment: @Holger `instructions` returns a `Stream<Instruction>`. I have not been able to find a way to "set them" in an implementation of `Instruction` that's type safe, my current solution is just to cast, and it works.

Comment: So when the source is a `Stream<Instruction>`, i.e. using a raw type, you can’t expect the subsequent generic code to work properly. You have to fix that source first.

Comment: @holger, updated to reflect more of that, I'm using ? because it could be, a boolean, or a long or whatever. I can see that maybe that could be a problem... but that doesn't really help me in fixing how to define the instruction in a strictly typed way in the first place.

Comment: ... to avoid unsafe casting

Comment: You already said, `INPUT` should be `OUT` and that’s all regarding how the `Instruction` interface should be declared. Of course, if you’re not using it correctly, but only with raw types or `?`, it simply won’t work.

Comment: @Holger so I should change my code to what exactly? please provide an answer

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to solve this so far is

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
public <INPUT> Function<Pair<INPUT, INPUT>, Optional<String>> pairToBuilder() {
    return (Function) this.pairOptionalFunction;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
public Function<Persistable<Long>, OUT> extractProperty()
{
    return (Function) extractProperty;
}
```